# Help with Tikz Circles

Tags: tikz-trees

I'm using TikZ to draw a Branch-and-Bound tree, and I need some help.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,           
    oneside,                
    a4paper,            
    english,        
    french,     
    spanish,            
    brazil              
    ]{abntex2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\tikzset{thick,
         tree node/.style = {align=center, inner sep=0pt, font = \scriptsize},
every label/.append style = {font=\scriptsize},
                 S/.style = {draw, circle, minimum size = 20mm, inner sep=0pt,
                             top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
               ENL/.style = {% edge node left
                             font=\footnotesize, left=1pt},
               ENR/.style = {% edge node right
                             font=\footnotesize, right=1pt},
                     grow = down,
         sibling distance = 2.8cm,
           level distance = 3cm
           }
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [S, label= 2:Some text here] {$PL0$}
    child{node [S] {$PL1$}
            child{node [S] {$PL3$}
            edge from parent node[ENL] {$x2 \leq 2$}}
            child{node [S] {$PL4$}
                 child{node [S] {$PL5$}
                     child{node [S] {$PL7$}
                     edge from parent node[ENL] {$x2 \leq 3$}}
                     child{node [S, label = 2:More text here] {$PL8$}
                     edge from parent node[ENR] {$x2 \geq 4$}}
          edge from parent node[ENL] {$x1 \leq 3$}}
          child{node [S, label = 2:Another text here] {$PL6$}
          edge from parent node[ENR] {$x1 \geq 4$}}
            edge from parent node[ENR] {$x2 \geq 3$}}
    edge from parent node[ENL] {$x1 \leq 4$}}
    child{node [S, label = 2:Last text here] {$PL2$}
    edge from parent node[ENR] {$x1 \geq 5$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{My Figure.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As result, you should get this figure:

[image]

Well, I need help with two things here:

1. Even using the `\centering` command, the figure is not centered. What am I missing here?
2. I need to write some more info inside those circles. For example, in the first one (PL0), it should have these aditional info:

[image]

I tried a lot of things, but couldn't make those info fit the circle.

Comment: 1. The figure *is* centered. In order to verify this, add `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` to the preamble of your document, and `\draw (current bounding box.south west)  rectangle (current bounding box.north
east);` before `\end{tikzpicture}`. 2. If you want more stuff in the circles, you need to add it to the node contents.

Comment: I see, thanks. But how can i add those 3 lines of info inside the circle? Like in the first line only "PL0", the second line "x1 = 4,333 e x2 = 2" and in the third line "f = 42".

Comment: You have to redefine `S`: ` S/.style = {draw, circle, minimum size = 20mm, inner sep=0pt,
                             top color=white, bottom color=blue!20,align=center},`, i.e. add `align=center` and then you can do `\node [S, label= 2:Some text here] {$PL0$\\ $x_1 = 4,333 e x_2 = 2$ \\ $f = 42$}`

Comment: Thank you! If you want, you can reply that as an answer, it solved my problem perfectly.

Comment: @CarLaTeX If you want to post one, please go ahead.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Oh, you are saying cats are better at trees than ducks? Perhaps, but maybe a koala will show up, they live in trees. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The figure *is* centered. In order to verify this, I added frames around the text area and the `tikzpicture`.
2. If you want more stuff in the circles, you need to add it to the node contents. If you want to allow for multiline texts, you need to add appropriate alignment (or `text width`) key such as `align=center`.

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,           
    oneside,                
    a4paper,            
    english,        
    french,     
    spanish,            
    brazil              
    ]{abntex2}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\tikzset{thick,
         tree node/.style = {align=center, inner sep=0pt, font = \scriptsize},
every label/.append style = {font=\scriptsize},
                 S/.style = {draw, circle, minimum size = 20mm, inner sep=0pt,
                             top color=white, bottom color=blue!20,
                             align=center}, %<-
               ENL/.style = {% edge node left
                             font=\footnotesize, left=1pt},
               ENR/.style = {% edge node right
                             font=\footnotesize, right=1pt},
                     grow = down,
         sibling distance = 2.8cm,
           level distance = 3cm
           }
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [S, label= 2:Some text here] {$PL0$}
    child{node [S] {$PL0$\\ $x_1 = 4,333$ e\\ $x_2 = 2$ \\ $f = 42$}
            child{node [S] {$PL3$}
            edge from parent node[ENL] {$x2 \leq 2$}}
            child{node [S] {$PL4$}
                 child{node [S] {$PL5$}
                     child{node [S] {$PL7$}
                     edge from parent node[ENL] {$x2 \leq 3$}}
                     child{node [S, label = 2:More text here] {$PL8$}
                     edge from parent node[ENR] {$x2 \geq 4$}}
          edge from parent node[ENL] {$x1 \leq 3$}}
          child{node [S, label = 2:Another text here] {$PL6$}
          edge from parent node[ENR] {$x1 \geq 4$}}
            edge from parent node[ENR] {$x2 \geq 3$}}
    edge from parent node[ENL] {$x1 \leq 4$}}
    child{node [S, label = 2:Last text here] {$PL2$}
    edge from parent node[ENR] {$x1 \geq 5$}};
\draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);    
\end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{My Figure.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also recommend looking at the `forest` package.

Comment: Thanks, upvoted :)